# How to indicate whether a Scanner has run of the end of a line?

Tags: java

I have written a for-loop which reads each line from stdin and returns the first non-whitespace character, but I don't know how indicate whether my Scanner has run off the end of the line I'm reading? Please advise!

Comment: can you show us your code plz

Comment: Paste your code please. Then we can see what you have tried and what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're reading each line, why do you need to worry about when the scanner runs off the line? Once you read a line, hold that line in a `String` variable and traverse the String. Use `String.length()` to determine the length, so you don't run off the end.